# Dynamic Allocation and Release in thread

Tags: c, linux, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am allocating some memory in a thread. When I call `pthread_detach(pthread_self());` the memory which is allocated for this thread by Linux should be released after thread is terminated by `pthread_exit();` or `pthread_cancel()`.

My question is that, should I also free the memory which I allocate with malloc? Also, if other functions in thread allocate some space, should I also free this space, even if thread is terminated and  `pthread_detach(pthread_self());` is called in thread?

```
void *test_thread(void * arg)
{
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());

    int *c = malloc(2048);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Don't kill threads violently through some forced API call. Instead signal them through application logic and have them clean up their own mess before returning.

Comment: Using `pthread_detach()` does not terminate a thread.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, you re right, i am misunderstood. I mean that thread is terminated but pthread_detach(pthread_self()); is also called in terminated thread.

Comment: @Lundin actually, i used pthread_cleanup_push() function to clean dynamic allocations, when thread is cancelled by other threads or thread is terminated by itself using pthread_exit(). Is this an another way to clean messes ?

Comment: I know that some SO users don't worry about manually cleaning up memory, since the OS will do it for you when the process terminates. .. up to you and your application. Personally I think ti's good practice and always try to clean up after myself.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that `pthread_detach` does for you is that you don't need to call `pthread_join` to clean up the internal thread data structures.

Any memory allocated via `malloc` still needs to be free'ed manually.  Either the thread needs to do that before it exits, or a pointer to the malloc'ed memory needs to be made available to another thread to clean up.

Answer (score 2):

*You'll* have to free all the memory *you* allocate in a `pthread` to avoid memory leak.  Since `pthread`s have a shared memory space, and it's perfectly acceptable for them to allocate memory and then exit, returning a pointer to it, there's no way for the C compiler or the system to know that the memory is no longer in use.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to view this is:  Managing memory you get via `malloc()` and similar functions such as `calloc()` is really simple.  You have to `free()` the exact value you received from `malloc()` (or `calloc()` or `valloc()` or ...).  Which thread does each operation within a process doesn't matter.

More succinctly:

You allocated it, you `free()` it.  Once.